# C# SQLite Doesn't work when I try to publish

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to build a small application that will have an embedded database.For that I used SQLite.  The program works fine when I debugg-it in Visual C# 2010 express but when i publish it and try to run it it gives me the following error:
Unhandled exception has occured in your application.....
**strong SQLite Error no such table:**

I don't really understand because it works fine when not published....
Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: What SQLite library do you use?

Comment: I am using System.Data.SQLite.dll

Comment: Does your application create the database file on the fly, or does it use an existing one?

Comment: It uses an existing one. I moved the file in the Debug folder for convenience...I created my database using the command line. The file that was created didn't have any extension so I added .db to it. It was giving the same error in the editor up until I read on the forum that I need to add an app.config file and it worked after that. The app.config file is as follows:                                            
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

SQLite when says there is not such table in a program which was working fine on development machine, then make sure it is making connection to right database.

In SQLite if it cannot find database at code-mentioned place, it will create one there. Size of it will be 0 KB. It will even open that database. Problem arises when data is fetched from it.

Then it gives this error. Use some Message Boxes/Debugger to check what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Yes, check to see if the database file is there and that the connection string is correct. Maybe you didn't include the database file in your install package? Or, maybe you want to check if the file exists before opening the database and create the tables if you are creating a new database file?

Comment: Got it! I was because I used a relative path instead of an absolute...It works now on my computer but I am wondering if it will work when I try to install it on other computers...will I have to create manually a new folder (same as in my computer)...Shouldn't this be done automatically...?                                                Thanks all for your responses!

Comment: @TzutzuSuntzutzu: In Code never hard code any paths. Use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` method to get folder where app is in. Moreover use `Path.Combine` to combine paths.